# overflow-x is not working with my second div as i am making slider with thumbnails in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, overflow

i want to make the second div overflow-x scroll but its not              working

```css
  #image_view a img{
 height: 400px;
 width: 600px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px;}
    #thumbnail{
    height: 120px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
    display: inline;
    }
    #thumbnail img{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 margin: auto;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 white-space: nowrap;}
```

```html
<div class=" col-lg-12 jumbotron">
    <div class="col-lg-10" id="image_view">
     <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image view"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12" id="thumbnail">
     
     <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="image">
     
                </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you want something like this > [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lksvy80w/) or snippet bellow

add `white-space:nowrap` to the `#thumbnail` not to the images and it should work

let me know if this is what you want.

```css
#image_view a img{
height: 400px;
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;}
#thumbnail{
height: 120px;
overflow-x: scroll;
display: inline;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

#thumbnail img {
  height: 100px;
width: 100px;
margin: auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" col-lg-12 jumbotron">
    <div class="col-lg-10" id="image_view">
     <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image view"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12" id="thumbnail">
     
     <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="image">
     <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="image">
     
    </div>
  </div>
```